# Getting child objects from a DB::table query in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have 3 tables: Posts, Tags and Post_tag. The last one is just a pivot table:

Posts:

```
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| title       | varchar(60)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at  | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at  | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Tags:

```
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name       | varchar(50)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Post_tag:

```
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| post_id    | int(10) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| tag_id     | int(10) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| created_at | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| updated_at | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Models are correct.

**Problem:**

I'm getting this error in the posts/index.blade.php file:

```
Undefined property: stdClass::$tags
(View: D:\laragon\www\laravel\resources\views\posts\index.blade.php)
```

In the posts/index.blade.php I have this @foreach inside a `@foreach ($posts as $post)` to list the tags a post belongs to.

```
@foreach($post->tags as $tag)
    <a class="btn btn-sm btn-info" href="/tag/{{ $tag->id }}">
        <span>{{ $tag->name }}</span>
    </a>
@endforeach
```

The previous @foreach only works if the controller sends `$posts = Post::all()`

However I can only send to the view some rows with some conditions (Published, author id, etc.). So I have this in the controller:

```
$posts = DB::table('posts')
                ->orderBy('posts.created_at', 'desc')
                ->where('town_id', '=', $request->session()->get('citySelected')->id)
                ->paginate(10);
```

I even tried to set up the joins:

```
$posts = DB::table('posts')
                ->join('post_tag', 'posts.id', '=', 'post_tag.post_id')
                ->join('tags', 'post_tag.tag_id', '=', 'tags.id')
                ->orderBy('posts.created_at', 'desc')
                ->where('town_id', '=', $request->session()->get('citySelected')->id)
                ->paginate(10);
```

But neither works, make me think DB::table only brings the parent objects but not the child objects.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load posts with related tags by using [`with`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) method:

```
$posts = Post::with('tags')
    ->where('town_id', session('citySelected')->id)
    ->latest()
    ->paginate(10);
```

Then you'll be able to do this:

```
@foreach ($posts as $post)
    @foreach($post->tags as $tag)
        <a class="btn btn-sm btn-info" href="/tag/{{ $tag->id }}">
            <span>{{ $tag->name }}</span>
        </a>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: I changed the :with('posts') for :with('tags') and it worked. Thanks so much

Comment: Great! I also learn about the  ->latest() and the cleaner where tag. Thanks bro!

Answer (score 0):

$posts pass to index.blade.php is a collecttion, not a object so your loop @foreach is wrong